# Bluebird Promise Order issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am watching videos to learn *MongoDB Express.js VueJS Node.js* (MEVN) stack.

And I want to create a seed directory and also use promise functions

```
//  const delay = require('delay')
const Promise = require('bluebird') 
const songs = require('./songs.json')
const users = require('./users.json')
const bookmarks = require('./bookmarks.json')
const historys = require('./history.json')

sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then( async function () {

    await Promise.all(
        users.map( user => {
            User.create(user)
        })
    ) 
    await Promise.all(
        songs.map( song => {
            Song.create(song)
        })
    )

     //I have to add this line
     //  ---> await delay(1000) 

    await Promise.all(
        bookmarks.map( bookmark => {
            Bookmark.create(bookmark)
        })
    )

    await Promise.all(
        historys.map( history => {
            History.create(history)
        })
    ) 
})
```

I have four tables with seeds to create, and the last two tables data must be created after the former two tables data. (They are foreign keys)

But every time I run this file, the last two tables data will be created first

The only way I can prevent this is to add delay(1000) between them.

I am wondering if there exists any efficient way to solve this issue~

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Race conditions like this one is always caused by that promises weren't properly chained.

A promise should be returned from `map` callback:

```
await Promise.all(
    users.map( user => User.create(user))
);
```

etc.

Not returning a value from `map` is virtually always a mistake. It can be prevented by using [`array-callback-return` ESLint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return).

If `User.create(user)`, etc. were Bluebird promises with default configuration, not chaining them would also result in [this warning](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/docs/docs/warning-explanations.md#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it).

Comment: Thank you ! I know what's going on. It is because { }  means not return value. And promise function must judge if its function returns value to chain them together!

Answer (score 1):

#### My assumption why your code might fail:

You're not returning the Promises that I guess `/(User|Song|Bookmark|History).create/g` return to the `Promise.all()` function, since your map callback is not returning anything.

If you're using Arrow functions with brackets, then you need to explicitly specify the return value (using the familar `return` keyword).

Otherwise you can just omit the curly brackets.

My suggestion is, that you refactor you're code by utilizing Promise `.then()`-Chaining.

For you're example, I would suggest something like this:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const songs = require('./songs.json')
const users = require('./users.json')
const bookmarks = require('./bookmarks.json')
const histories = require('./history.json')

sequelize.sync({
    force: true
}).then(() =>
    Promise.all(
        users.map(user =>
            User.create(user)
        )
    ).then(() =>
        Promise.all(
            songs.map(song =>
                Song.create(song)
            )
        )
    ).then(() =>
        Promise.all(
            bookmarks.map(bookmark =>
                Bookmark.create(bookmark)
            )
        )
    ).then(() =>
        Promise.all(
            histories.map(history =>
                History.create(history)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: There is no second possibility. `await` internally chains a promise with `then`, `await bluebirdPromise` is equivalent to `Promise.resolve(bluebirdPromise).then(...)`.

Comment: @estus thanks for the clarification, I didn't know. Cool username btw. I'll update my answer.